# How to find duplicate record sql

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

Query

```
SELECT AV.ItemID as ItemIDe, AV.uid,  ui.Count, U.Name, u.Surname,
u.UID as UserID, av.Value, av1.Value, AV2.Value  
FROM AttribValues as AV  
full join AttribValues as AV2 on AV2.AttribID = 3 AND AV2.Value = '12' 
                                 AND AV2.ItemID = AV.ItemID 
full join AttribValues as AV1 on AV1.AttribID = 2 AND AV1.Value = 'zielony' 
                                 AND AV1.ItemID = AV.ItemID 
join UsersItems as UI on Ui.UID = AV.ItemID
join Users as U on u.UID = ui.UserID  
WHERE ((AV.AttribID = 1 AND AV.Value = '517750069') OR (AV1.Value IS NOT NULL 
OR AV2.Value IS NOT NULL))  AND DateEnd > GETDATE ()
```

and are in duplicate records in Av.ItemID

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  Also, I presume this is for `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), AV.ItemID as ItemIDe, AV.uid,  ui.Count, U.Name, u.Surname, u.UID as UserID, av.Value, av1.Value, AV2.Value  

FROM AttribValues as AV  
full join AttribValues as AV2 on AV2.AttribID = 3 AND AV2.Value = '12' AND AV2.ItemID = AV.ItemID 
full join AttribValues as AV1 on AV1.AttribID = 2 AND AV1.Value = 'zielony' AND AV1.ItemID = AV.ItemID 

join UsersItems as UI on Ui.UID = AV.ItemID
join Users as U on u.UID = ui.UserID  

WHERE ((AV.AttribID = 1 AND AV.Value = '517750069') OR (AV1.Value IS NOT NULL OR AV2.Value IS NOT NULL))  AND DateEnd > GETDATE ()

GROUP BY AV.ItemID, AV.uid,  ui.Count, U.Name, u.Surname, u.UID, av.Value, av1.Value, AV2.Value

HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```